# make a row or a column fixed along all worksheet

Tags: vba

I want to make a workbook and make one row and one column in it fixed and appear on all worksheets.
can you help me guys?

I know how to freeze panes on a single worksheet but not on whole workbook

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub FreezePanes()

Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim current As Worksheet

Set current = ActiveSheet

For Each wsh In Worksheets

  wsh.Activate
  Range("B2").Select
  ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Next wsh

current.Activate

End Sub
```